# Is it possible to make a multiple line coordinates in QGIS 2.12.1 map comsposer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-2.12, coordinate-system

I'm trying to display a 2 line coordinates, where the thousands are on the top row, and the units are on the lower row. 
I've tried to custom coordinates using the following expression:

```
left(@grid_number,3)  ||  '\n'  || right( @grid_number ,3)
```

But instead of a new line, I receive a font separating the 2 expressions that should be presented:

[image]